# How to I add a "backup" image background for header if device can't play the video

Tags: html, image, video, background, header

So with HTML5 video there is a possibilty to add multiple video files and as I understand browser/device picks out most suitable video from these files. I am wondering how to I add a image as a background if video fails to play. I currently tried this solution but probably I just can't load an image inside a video tag as I understand.

```
<div class="custom-header-background" >

<video autoplay loop muted>
 <source src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/vid2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/vid2.m4v" type="video/m4v">
<source src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/img2.jpg" type="image/jpg">


Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it make sense to absolutely position a div on top of your video player with your "backup" image?

Set that to `display: none;`

And if your video fails to play, you can then set that to `display: block;`
My understanding is that you can also hook into the video player onError event like this:

```
// Code to find your player

yourplayer.onerror = () => {

document.getElementById("yourimage").style.display = "block";

}
```

Check out the pen I made:

https://codepen.io/foreza/pen/XWmoaNB

Comment: Yea that did the trick, thank you! I also had some trouble with linking template directory to .js file so I added <script type="text/javascript">
var templateUrl = '<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>';
</script> to header.php and the code in .js file where I linked the video is myPlayer.src = ""+templateUrl+"/img/visitruhnu2.m4v"; . Cheers mate!